# Better approach than using DBlink multiple times?

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql

I have a for loop inside a for loop and I'm using a DBlink inside that. Execution of that was taking a lot of time. I replaced it with a global temporary table in which data will be inserted through the DBlink before the loops start. There was a big improvement in performance(Elapsed time). Is there any other approach which will give an even better performance?

Comment: Without an example of your code, it's very difficult to say. If by "for loops", you mean "cursor for loops", then in the majority of cases, you should be able to combine the two cursors into a single cursor (y'know, let the optimizer handle the join, rather than you reinvented nested loop joins!). If all you're doing with your loops is ultimately updating or inserting the data somewhere, then you could probably get away with a single update, insert or merge statement that does all the work in one fell swoop. In short, provide more info about what your code does, and we can help you further.

Comment: Please provide your code base and what you have tried yet.

Comment: My problem is not with for loops. I need a replacement for DBlink.

Comment: @Nitish How much data is being passed over the link?  If it's a small amount of data per connection there is probably no better way to do this than database links.  If there are a lot of links then running them in parallel may help.  Unfortunately normal parallelism does not run multiple links at the same time, but you can create that parallelism with DBMS_SCHEDULER or with the new 12c feature `PQ_CONCURRENT_UNION` hint.